# Display unsecured Intranet pages in SF

Tags: apex, security

I have company intranet pages are  insecure webpages , and I want to make them accessible by a tab.  From what I understand, you can only put secure pages on tabs. Can someone recommend a work around? As a heads up, we use IE, and I'd prefer my users don't get a "this page contains secure and unsecure content..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to display web pages inside of Salesforce from another domain is via an iframe. An iframe on an secure page that displays a page that is non-SSL is going to give you that content warning in the browser. The only way forward that I can see here is making your intranet SSL-enabled.